# Is there some function in Android SDK which is an analogue of jQuery.param()?

Tags: android, jquery, http, serialization

There is a function param() in jQuery library

It serializes JS-object into a string set of HTTP parameters

Example: object {a:'x',b:{c:[0,1]}}

```
$.param({a:'x',b:{c:[0,1]}})
"a=x&b%5Bc%5D%5B%5D=0&b%5Bc%5D%5B%5D=1"
```

This string is encoded by encodeURIComponent()

It could be decoded by decodeURIComponent()

```
decodeURIComponent($.param({a:'x',b:{c:[0,1]}}))
"a=x&b[c][]=0&b[c][]=1"
```

We see that the object is converted into a set of parameters:

```
a=x
b[c][]=0
b[c][]=1
```

I need to do the same serialization in my Android application

I have to send data in the same format as is being done by jQuery

So the question is:

Is there some function in Android SDK which is an analogue of jQuery.param() ?

Answer (score 0):

While people stays silent I offer my handmade solution on Kotlin:

```
fun serialize(data: JSONObject): String {
    var result = arrayListOf<String>()

    fun parse(value: Any, name: String, alt: String? = null) {
        if (value is JSONObject) {
            val keys = value.keys()
            while (keys.hasNext())
                keys.next().let {
                    parse(value[it], "$name[$it]")
                }
        } else if (value is JSONArray) {
            for (i in 0 until value.length())
                parse(value[i], "$name[$i]", "$name[]")
        } else {
            result.add(Uri.encode(alt ?: name) + "=" + Uri.encode("$value"))
        }
    }

    val keys = data.keys()
    while (keys.hasNext())
        keys.next().let {
            parse(data[it], it)
        }

    return result.joinToString("&")
}
```

This variant works identically to jQuery. It would be nice to avoid such homework though :-)